Duplicate items in the content tree of Sitecore Content Editor
I am seeing duplicate items in one of our server. When I open Content Editor, all the items under the content tree have the duplicate item.

I have tried cleaning up the DBs. Also, performed reindexing.
This is happening for Sitecore 10.3 and it is hosted on Azure Web App
Since the it is hosted on Azure Web App, I do not have the flexibility to try the answers mentioned in Duplicate Content Items appearing during Sitecore Upgrade to 10.2
Also, I have the Vanila instance of Sitecore 10.3, with some custom configurations.

@SumitBhatia I have updated the question with more details.

I faced the similar issue, it was due to the dataprovider configuration at the database level.
Starting from Sitecore 10, the dataprovider contains 2 params headProvider and readOnlyDataProviders and should be of type CompositeDataProvider. In order to patch the dataprovider configuration, it should be configured under the headProvider param as below.
<database id="web" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery">
  <dataProviders>
      <dataProvider type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
         <param desc="headProvider">
            <dataProvider param1="$(id)">
                <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                    <patch:delete />
                </prefetch>
            </dataProvider>
        </param>
     </dataProvider>
  </dataProviders>
</database>

You can make sure the custom data provider added inside your solution, inherits the above structure to avoid duplication of content items.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

I have updated my custom data provider structure as mentioned above and restarted the app. Issue is resolved.
